# How are query parameter name modifiers specified in an Open API Specification?

Tags: openapi, hl7-fhir

My question is how people are handling modifiers to either the query parameter name or the query parameter value in their Open API Specification.

For example,HL7 FHIR allows for both query parameter modifiers, e.g.

```
GET /Patient?gender:not=male
```

and for query parameter value modifiers:

```
GET /Patient?birthdate=le2000-01-01
```

My question is not specifically about FHIR APIs, but APIs in general that use this approach.

What's being done in practice out there? FYI, I found an Open API spec for all of FHIR, and from what I can tell, their Open API spec did not address query parameter modifiers.  They put the base parameter in the spec (e.g. gender) but did not include anything in the spec to show that application query parameters can have suffixes attached to their name.

Options I've considered on parameter name modifications:

1. Create a separate query parameter for every parameter+modified combo. This would result in a spec that would be fully compliant (allowing tools that perform analysis of message traffic against specs to still work), but could result in an unwieldy spec if your modifier list is large.
2. Put some kind of extension, e.g. `x-modifiers` into the API spec to address this, like:

```
...
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: birthdate
    description: Restricts results to the value (and modifiers) specified.
    schema:
      type: string
    x-modifiers: 
      - before
      - after
      - onOrBefore 
      - onOrAfter
```

For parameter value modifications, I'm guessing they are best handled using the `patterns` keyword, although this does have the unfortunate side effect of requiring everything to be a string, so the example of the `birthdate` search above could not have `birthdate` as `format: date`.